# mySQL giving more results than my query is supposed to

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to construct a MySQL-query, where the result is based on the given ingredients.

If said that I provide Tequila, Orangejuice and Grenadine, I want the result to be Tequila Sunrise ONLY. Not everything that has either ingredient in them.

My current query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM drink 
INNER JOIN mix 
ON drink.id = mix.drinkid 
WHERE Ing IN ('Tequila', 'Apelsinjuice', 'Grenadine')
```

I would be so grateful for any help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide a data set for both tables, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: My problem is solved, will think of that for next time though, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I prefer doing this with aggregation and a `having` clause because that is the most flexible approach:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM drink INNER JOIN mix 
     ON drink.id = mix.drinkid 
group by drink.id
having sum(Ing = 'Tequila') > 0 and
       sum(Ing = 'Apelsinjuice') > 0 and
       sum(Ing = 'Grenadine') > 0
```

Each `sum()` in the `having` clause is counting up the number of rows with the given ingredient.  The `> 0` ensures that the ingredient is present.  The `and` insists that all three ingredients be in the recipe.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I can't explain how much I appreciate it! THANK YOU!

Comment: @SimonRöstin . . . Glad you found it useful.